# node-webkit loading module fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I'm starting with node-webkit and I cannot load a module (a JS file) I made in my project.
Here is the tree view :
root

```
|-index.html
|-js/
|---app.js
|---resources/
|-----angular..jquery..
|---crawler/
|-----leboncoin/
|-------lbcCrawler.js
```

I want to load the module "mycrawler" in the "app.js", but I get the following error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'js/crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:334:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:360:17)
    at require (module.js:376:17)
    at window.require (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:1:112)
    at eval (file:///C:/Users/acouty/git/webkit%20fooling/js/ui/app.js:3:10)
```

My files :
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resources/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resources/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

var cc = require("crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js");
```

lbcCrawler.js

```
var simpleCrawler = require("simplecrawler");

var BASE_URL = "http://www.leboncoin.fr/annonces/offres/:region/occasions/?f=a&th=1&q=:item";
var DEFAULT_REGION = "ile_de_france";

var crawl = function(item, region, results)
{
    if (_.isUndefined(region) || _.isNull(region))
    {
        region = DEFAULT_REGION;
    }
    console.log("Looking for %s in %s", item, region);

    var queryURL = BASE_URL.replace(":region", region).replace(":item", item);

    var lbcCrawler = simpleCrawler.crawl(queryURL);
    lbcCrawler.interval(500);
    lbcCrawler.on("fetchComplete", function(queueItem, responseBuffer, response) {
        results.push(queueItem);
    });

    lbcCrawler.start();
}
```

---

EDIT

I tried something else :
What I want is to `use my modules like dependencies`. The ui part is for angularJS, and other folders for the node-only part.
I tried to do something more logcal in my thought : create an index.js and package.json files into lebecoincrawler directory.
Now, I want a ui/ folder file to require this. But I cannot...

```
I tried :
var cc = require("../crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js");
var cc = require("./../crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js");
var cc = require("./js/crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js");
```

I can't get it to work and I can't believe it's impossible to do, otherwise I cannot imagine how my projet folder would be.. flat :(.

---

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `require` to start with your current directory explicitly, by adding `./` to the beginning of your path:

```
var cc = require("./crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js");
```

Otherwise, node will look in a node_modules directory, or similar, cf:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm

EDIT:

For some reason, that's not working in node-webkit, but this might do the trick:

```
path = require('path');
var cc = require(path.join(process.cwd(),"js/crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js"));
```

EDIT2:

I think I've got it figured out now.  `__dirname` and `__filename` are not defined in the node REPL, nor in a node-webkit script tag, even if your script tag is used to include your .js file, as in

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Thus, if you call require `lbcCrawler.js` from `app.js` you'd need to require it as

```
var cc = require("./js/crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js");
```

because the path is where you start node-webkit, e.g. where index.html lives.

However, if you do

```
<script>require('js/app.js')</script>
```

then `__dirname` and `__filename` are defined and `require` will search from where the app.js file  lives, i.e. you would do:

```
var cc = require(path.join("./crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js"));
```

Because of this discrepancy, you might be better off depending on the value of `process.cwd` (as in the first edit above) which should be the same in either case, whether app.js is included via `require` or `script`.

Comment: oooo okay !
I read the documentation, but as english is not my first language I misunderstood ! I'll try it tomorrow when I get back to work :).

Comment: re OldGeeksGuide, I tried something else, you can see this in the EDIT part of my question :). Thanks

Comment: Hmm, that's unexpected.  You've got me curious now.  In the meantime, how about trying this:  path = require('path');

var cc = require(path.join(process.cwd(),"js/crawler/leboncoin/lbcCrawler.js"));

Comment: Imo a better solution would be to put the modules in /node_modules of your app. This is the "official" solution: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Using-Node-modules