# Node-webkit works on Mac, crashes and can't load module on Windows

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I've created a full node-webkit app that works fine on the Mac OSX version of node-webkit. Everything works, it loads a key external nodeJS module (marked), and the world is good.

However, when I try to run the app on the Windows version of Node-webkit as [described in the Wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-run-apps), the app crashes immediately (in fact, it crashes immediately when I try all the options: dragging a folder onto nw.exe, dragging an app.nw compressed folder, and running both from the command line).

The only thing that gets me closer is opening nw.exe and then pointing the node-webkit location bar to the index file. Then I get this error:

> **Uncaught node.js Error**
>   Error: Cannot find module 'marked'

I tried commenting out the code that requires marked:

```
var marked = require('marked');
```

That returns the app to crashing immediately. I assumed it was because of context issues between node.js and the node-webkit browser, but those seem to not be at fault since I tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842907/node-webkit-loading-module-fails) to make sure it finds the correct file for the marked module...went right back to immediate crashing.

I'm out of ideas because the crashes don't seem to leave me any way of knowing what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you specific the crashed nw version on Windows platform?
2. And please provide a sample code, I want to reproduce it because my test code does not crash (I only have one line JS code).

`var marked = require('marked');`